# Is azure functions a right fit for long running tasks?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-webjobs

A ***TCP Host server*** is located ***on-premises***. Now from Azure environment I need to connect with the *host server*. Once the connection is established, the *host server* will be sending messages continuously, and the received messages will be forwarded to Azure Service Bus queue.

I was given the following architecture(simplified). The architecture proposes a function app which will be used to connect with the on-prem server, and then receives messages continuously, and then place the messages on to the service bus queue.

[image]

Per Microsoft guidelines it says we must [avoid long running functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-best-practices#avoid-long-running-functions), as it causes timeout issues.

Considering the above requirement (establishing connection and receiving messages - i.e. long running task) and MS guidelines, is Azure Function a right choice? I believe a web job or a web app would be a better fit for this purpose.

Comment: Could the host server not reach out to the function rather than the function initiating the communication? You can create HTTP functions as a sort of WebAPI which then could forward the message onwards? Or even better alter the host to send messages to Service Bus directly. If the host cannot be altered there are other options available beyond Azure Functions

Comment: thanks for the response, in this case, the host server is not allowed to initiate any communication with other systems.

Comment: Because of that, a function is the wrong technology choice, you could easily switch out the function for a [Continuous WebJob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-create) that lives in an Azure Web App. Web Apps and Function Apps are both types of Azure App Services so it's quite a simple change.

Comment: thanks @ConnorDickson, I totally agree with you. I would never choose function for this requirement either, unfortunately this has been the proposed architecture and as a dev am trying to convince the architect to modify.

Comment: Good luck! I'll reply as the Answer now :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A function is the wrong technology choice in this case, you could easily switch out the function for a [Continuous WebJob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-create) that lives in an Azure Web App. Web Apps and Function Apps are both types of Azure App Services so it's quite a simple change.

Answer (score 7):

You can use Azure Functions for long running process. The recommendation is to move the process part to Activities provided by Durable Framework:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview?tabs=csharp

Comment: Thanks Thiago, I agree that we can achieve the long running tasks, but is it a right way to solve the above problem(once we start the function app,  we need to run the function for ever)?

Answer (score 2):

> as per Microsoft guidelines it says we must avoid long running
> functions, as it causes timeout issues.

Yes this is the recommended way when you are using Azure function that runs for less that 60 minutes. azure Function in premium plan supports guaranteed [`60 minutes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#functiontimeout)  .However for long running scenarios you can use Durable Function which are intented to solve complex scenarios which lets you split up your jobs into smaller junks.

In your scenario i would recommend you to add a middleware component such as [eventhub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/serverless/event-processing) which could retain the data for certain amount of time and use different function to process them later asynchronously.

Comment: Thanks Sajeetharan, I agree with you about the durable functions, but is it the right way to solve this problem(connecting with an external server and receive messages contineously), I thought web jobs would be a better option than durable functions to implement, am I missing something?

Comment: It depends, you can achieve using Webjobs also. Otherwise you can place queue middleware and make sure the messages are processed

Answer (score 1):

Few queries I have:

query 1 - will TCP Host server sending messages continuously to Azure Function or will Azure Function talk to 'TCP Host Server' and get the message and then add to the Service Bus Queue?

Query 2 - if Azure Function will talk to the 'TCP Host Server' and get message, will it be like makes a connection, gets a message, adds message to queue and disconnects OR will it be make one connection which is never ending and keeps getting messages and keeps adding them to the queue?

if it makes a connection to get one message or more than one message lets say every few seconds or few minutes then you can use Azure Function. In this scenario you can use a CRON job type Azure function with a schedule to achieve this and this will not count as a long running Function as it will always end in a schedule you define.

But if you want to make one long connection, then I would not recommend using Azure Function, even with Durable Function as it beats the concept of durable Function as well as it supposed to end. Either use Event Hub if you can send the message from your on-prem server to Event Hub. Event Hub would be a very scalable way to do this as you can scale it up if you have millions or trillions of messages and it is specifically built for this. You can also use Azure IoT Hub with Protocol Gateway, where your gateway can translate your TCP messages to an IoT Hub supported protocol (HTTP, AMQP or MQTT).

I know I made this confusing, if you want to keep it simple then use Function but with a scheduled CRN job like manner to avoid the long running pitfall.

Comment: In regards to q1- yes the Az function is responsible for establishing connection with the ’TCP Host Server’ and receive messages from then on.

Q2- It’s going to be one long connection, as we need to collect messages in real time and add them onto the service bus queue.

I totally agree with you on the recommendation’s about event hub, unfortunately due to limitation on the on-prem tcp host server, this is not in the options.

As you rightly mentioned, as it requires one long connection, the functions/durable aren’t the right choice for this problem, I recommended to go with Web Jobs.

Comment: do remember WebJobs are only available for C# and you can scale them up but not scale them out.

Comment: not sure what you mean by 'Only available for C#'?, cos web jobs do support multiple file types, please refer this. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-create#acceptablefiles

Comment: ahh my apologies if i was not clear, I meant to use WebJobs you are limited with .NET as it only has 1 SDK which is available for .NET  or at least that was my understanding - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-sdk-get-started