# Subscribe to Google PubSub from Azure Function App

Tags: python, c#, azure, azure-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm trying to figure out the best way to subscribe to a Google PubSub subscription from Azure Function App. My solution below "works" -- meaning I can start it up locally and it will pull messages that are published to the subscribed-to topic. But this can't be the right way of doing this, so I'm looking for better ideas.

I'm kicking off a timer and then listening for messages. But would a Durable app be better? The described patterns in the documentation don't fit this.

Another approach might be using the timer, but then pulling instead of listening asynchronously?

I want to log these messages and publish them to Azure ESB.

Any advice or examples would be appreciated. I'm happy to use C# or Python -- or any language for that matter.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace NetEaiDemo
{
    public class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public async Task Run([TimerTrigger("*/30 * * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");

            string projectId = "project1";
            string subscriptionId = "subscription1";

            SubscriptionName subscriptionName = new SubscriptionName(projectId, subscriptionId);
            SubscriberClient subscriber = await SubscriberClient.CreateAsync(subscriptionName);
            List<PubsubMessage> receivedMessages = new List<PubsubMessage>();
            // Start the subscriber listening for messages.
            await subscriber.StartAsync((msg, cancellationToken) =>
            {
                receivedMessages.Add(msg);
                Console.WriteLine($"Received message {msg.MessageId} published at {msg.PublishTime.ToDateTime()}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Text: '{msg.Data.ToStringUtf8()}'");
                // Stop this subscriber after one message is received.
                // This is non-blocking, and the returned Task may be awaited.
                subscriber.StopAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));
                // Return Reply.Ack to indicate this message has been handled.
                return Task.FromResult(SubscriberClient.Reply.Ack);
            });

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you consider push subscription instead of pull?

Comment: This is an integration between a few system, already functioning with a sub-optimal integration layer that's not scalable. I'm working with endpoints I can't change without a lot of trouble, so I need to work with the subscription, since it's all I have.

Comment: The problem is that the polling is "infinite". I already achieved a dirty things with Cloud Functions and Cloud Scheduler to listen the pull subscription 55 seconds (I set a timer to stop the listening), and to call the function every minute. It's like a full time service up but like that you have low latency message processing thank to pulling, and serverless usage of Cloud Functions. it's not cost efficient compare to VM or even GKE autopilot (solution that I could recommend on Google Cloud), but it worked!

Comment: So is your solution the same as I have above, but with a cron * * * * * and StopAsync timespan of 55 ?

Comment: Yes, I haven't better. Or to host your code on long lived duration platform (a VM for instance)

Comment: Reading this topic, maybe these Continuous WebJobs are a good solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63490224/is-azure-functions-a-right-fit-for-long-running-tasks

Comment: Maybe yes, I'm not a Azure expert (or even beginner!)